# linux open returns 0

Tags: linux, system-calls

The code is like this:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
```

"max open files" is 1024. The process may opened hundreds of files.
At the beginning, it works good. After a while, open returns 0. I don't know why. Help!!! Thanks advance!

*ps: It's not `int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY) == -1;`*

Comment: If you try limiting the number of open files by changing your code, the behaviour changes? I mean, being sure that you don't have more than 1024 open files at any time..

Comment: But if there're too many open files, it should return -1 with the errno be set to EMFILE.

Comment: Yes, and i meant something else..ah, it's almost 6am here..time to sleep :D Take a look here (and accepted answer in that question), the problem is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135159/socket-returns-0-c-client-server-app

Answer (score 6):

When `open` returns 0, it's telling you that you should use fd 0 if you want to use the file you just opened.

Did you perchance close stdin?

Comment: 0 means stdin, but it should return a num bigger than 3? Isn't it?

Comment: @user2253605: It'll return whatever fd it allocated.  If you closed stdin, 0 is completely fair game.

Answer (score 0):

admin can change some parameters of ulimit
admin can set "ulimit -n 2000" and number of open files per process can be 2000

Comment: if there're too many open files, it should return -1 with the errno be set to EMFILE.However it returns 0. why?

Answer (score 0):

It is returning 0 because you have used relational operator here.
Something == another is always 0 or 1
Here in your case it is telling you that open didnt returned  -1.